# change header color of jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am working with jqgrid. I want to change the color of titlebar but I am failed to do so. I dont know what silly mistake I am doing. I tried this but It didnt work

```
.ui-th-column, .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th.ui-th-column {
    border-bottom: 0 none;
    border-top: 0 none;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: orange;
}
```

I also tried `.ui-jqgrid .ui-widget-header{background-color: yellow !important;}` but it also didnt work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rsHmj/56/

Comment: use a tool like chrome inspector and check the classes of element and it's parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-widget-header {
    background-color: orange;
    background-image: none
}
```

It changes the background color of the titlebar. To change the background color of the column headers you should use for example the following CSS rule

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-labels th.ui-th-column {
    background-color: orange;
    background-image: none
}
```

Instead of setting both `background-color` and removing background image you can specify `background` property (for example `background: orange;`), which set many properties at once (`background-color`, `background-image`, `background-repeat`, `background-attachment`, `background-position`).

Comment: Oh sure. I just missed it. Done

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
.ui-widget-header {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    background: none;
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: I have tried but it also didnt work. Any kind of change is not affecting jqgrid .I dont know the reason.

Comment: I put it in ui.jqgrid.css file.